# Переключение на modal view в Tab Bar

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios7

Доброго всем времени суток! Вопрос по XCode 5.

Предполагаю, что вопрос обнажит всю мою неопытность, однако у меня возникли сложности с открытием одной из вкладок Tab Bar в режиме modal. Подобный механизм реализован в программе Instagram, когда при открытии средней вкладки вылетает новое модальное окно добавления нового изображения.

У меня два варианта на уме:

1. Привязать к обычному ViewController, в частности прописать в viewDidLoad, программно запуск еще одного окна в модальном режиме;
2. Каким-то образом при щелчке на нужной вкладке сразу открывать модальное окно.
   Первый вариант мне кажется диким костылем, а для второго я не сумел настроить открытие вьюшки в режиме modal.

Если кто-нибудь подкинет идею, как это реализовать, буду безмерно благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Станьте делегатом таб бара или таб бар контроллера, реализуйте соответствующий метод и презентуйте экран. Что-то вроде этого:

```
func tabBarController(controller:UITabBarController!, didSelectViewController viewController:UIViewController!) {
    If (viewController is MyFakeViewController) {
        presentViewController(neededVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Еще один способ - использовать UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, тогда никаких трюков не нужно, просто на один из контроллеров (или сколько угодно) в UITabBarController будет презентован кастомно.
UITabBarController поддерживает кастомные переходы, для этого нужно реализовать пару методов.
Вот тут есть пара примеров: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2163555&seqNum=2